# Como ler um xml de retorno contendo CDATA no PHP

Tags: php, xml

Ola, não sou muito familiarizado com este tipo de retorno em uma requisição SoapClient (Aliás, não sou muito familiarizado com SOAP).
O retorno possui um elemento "exemplo]]", e quando tento ler o arquivo, ele imprime todo em uma unica string.

```
        $url = "http://localhost:12/mtd1/mtd.asmx?wsdl";

    $clientSoap = new SoapClient($url, array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2));


    $params = array('Usuario'=>'user', 'Senha'=>'1234', 'limite'=>$ultima);

    $positions = $clientSoap->BuscaEventos($params);
```

Ele retorna algo como:

```
<BuscarEventosResponse>
    <BuscarEventos>
         <![CDATA[<TeleEvento> <NumeroSequencia>1010</NumeroSequencia></TeleEvento>]]
    </BuscarEventos>
</BuscarEventosResponse>
```

Ao listar os elementos filhos da tag BuscarEventos, ele retorna uma unica string eliminando os filhos.
Alguém poderia me auxiliar neste "problema"?

Comment: "ele retorna uma unica string eliminando os filhos", poderia detalhar melhor essa parte?

Comment: Quando recebo, ele esta neste formato <![CDATA[<TeleEvento> <NumeroSequencia>1</NumeroSequencia> <IdSeqMsg> 95372 </IdSeqMsg></TeleEvento>]] pegando pelo SoapUI, pelo PHP quando dou print na tela, ele retorna assim: string(636012) " 1 95372 0 0 1 92 22/12/2018 02:59:09 0 34 E8B69 03. Como uma uníca string

Comment: Sim, porque é um XML dentro da *string*. Aparece desse jeito porque você tentou exibir o XML dentro de um HTML sem escapá-lo. Se quer extrair os dados desta *string*, precisará analisá-la como XML.

Comment: Valeu @Anderson Carlos Woss, foi isso mesmo, utilizei _new SimpleXMLElement_ no valor retornado e ele gerou um objeto com os campos do xml.